# Reversing the colors in a persp3D plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am working with the `persp3D()` function in the `GA` package in `R` and I am having trouble getting the colors to be reversed. Currently, using `heat.colors` makes the color be red where its low and white/yellow where the surface is high. I would like to have the reverse of this. The reason being is that when I use the `image()` function, that is how the colors come out (i.e., red low, yellow high). Here is an example.

```
library(GA)

y <- x <- seq(-10, 10, length=60)
f <- function(x,y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z <- outer(x, y, f)

image(x, y, z)

persp3D(x, y, z, col.palette = heat.colors, phi = 30, theta = 225,
        box = TRUE, border = NA, shade = .4)
```

[image]

[image]

I would have thought using something like `col.palette = rev(heat.colors)` but it complains about that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that `heat.colors` is a function that has an argument `rev`.

```
args(heat.colors)
function (n, alpha, rev = FALSE) 
NULL
```

One easy way to change the default is to define your own `heat.colors`. We could spend a lot of effort reviewing the source for `persp3D` and find out exactly how `heat.colors` is called, or we could just use `...` to pass any other arguments on. I prefer the lazy way:

```
my.heat.colors <- function(...) heat.colors(..., rev=TRUE)
```

Now it's easy:

```
persp3D(x, y, z, col.palette = my.heat.colors, phi = 30, theta = 225,
        box = TRUE, border = NA, shade = .4)
```

[image]